# Does WHEN clause in an insert all query when loading into multiple tables in Snowflake add a virtual field over each row and then load in bulk?

Tags: sql, insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bulkinsert, data-ingestion

How `WHEN` clause evaluate values of columns in order to insert only new values and skip existing ones when using the following query:

```
INSERT ALL
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DEST WHERE DEST.ID = NEW_ID) = 0 THEN
INSERT INTO DEST (ID) VALUES (NEW_ID)
SELECT NEW_ID FROM SRC
```

I tried with `WHEN NEW_ID NOT IN (SELECT...) THEN`

But it didn't work and threw an error of unsupported.

Does it create a virtual column in all rows with values of true or false and then add all rows having true as a result?

Answer (score 0):

Using `EXISTS`:

```
INSERT ALL
WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DEST WHERE DEST.ID = NEW_ID) THEN
INTO DEST (ID) VALUES (NEW_ID) 
SELECT NEW_ID FROM SRC;
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE DEST(ID INT);
INSERT INTO DEST VALUES(1);

CREATE TABLE SRC(NEW_ID INT);
INSERT INTO SRC VALUES (1),(2);


SELECT * FROM DEST;
-- 1

--EXPLAIN USING TABULAR
INSERT ALL
WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DEST WHERE DEST.ID = NEW_ID) THEN
INTO DEST (ID) VALUES (NEW_ID) 
SELECT NEW_ID FROM SRC;


SELECT * FROM DEST;
-- 1
-- 2
```

Comment: How does work ? Does when filter rows to new ones to be later added ?

Comment: @alim1990 The internals are probably known only to Snowflake engineers.  Some hints could be seen using `EXPLAIN USING TABULAR`. " Does when filter rows to new ones to be later added ?" - Each WHEN is independent when INSERT ALL is used